Understanding the significance of a type of fractional derivative
My question is concerned with what is called the "conformable fractional derivative", in the paper that introduces it, the claim of it being a substitute to the Riemann-Liouville and Caputo is made based on it satisfying the usual rules of differentiation such as sum, product, quotient, but to my knowledge, a fractional derivative can't be local nor can it satisfy the Leibniz product rule.
So I am a bit puzzled about how a definition of an operator that acts as rescaling by $x^{1-\alpha}$ to the usual derivative, gains such attention in fractional differentiation studies.

Is the paper that introduces it Khalil, Al Horani, Yousef, and Sababheh - A new definition of fractional derivative?

@LSpice Yes, that is right
